# grep -no is not functioning properly

Tags: grep

Typically when using `grep -no` every single match has a line number. For example when typing `grep -no "[A|a]" chr22.fa` I expect:

```
$ grep -v ">" chr22.fa | grep -o -n "[A|a]" | head -n 17
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210201:A
210202:A
210202:A
```

However, as of recent the output looks something like:

```
$ grep -v ">" chr22.fa | grep -o -n "[A|a]" | head -n 17
210201:A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

Regardless of what I'm searching for and which chromosome txt file I'm dealing with the same issue. Does anyone know why this incorrect format is occurring? Thank you in advance for the help.

Edit: Result of hexdump -C on short file with random sequence of letters:

```
00000000  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 0a 62 42 42 42 42 |AAAAAAAAAA.bBBBB|
00000010  41 41 41 0a 42 42 41 42  41 41 42 41 42 41 42 42  |AAA.BBABAABABABB|
00000020  41 42 41 0a 41 42 55 57  42 41 55 41 42 57 44 55  |ABA.ABUWBAUABWDU|
00000030  42 57 55 44 55 57 44 55  0a 41 48 55 44 48 47 55  |BWUDUWDU.AHUDHGU|
00000040  45 47 55 0a 68 65 69 66  68 69 65 68 66 0a 77 65  |EGU.heifhiehf.we|
00000050  68 66 69 68 77 65 66 0a  41 41 0a 68 73 65 66 69 |hfihwef.AA.hsefi|
00000060  68 48 41 0a                                       |hHA.|
00000064
```

Comment: I'm doing the following: `grep -no "[A|a]" chr22.fa`. Though regardless of what I'm searching for and which chromosome txt file I'm dealing with the outcome is the same.

Comment: Question updated. The goal isn't to count every match. The goal is to know what line number every single "A" is associated with.

Comment: Similar output can happen if there's a carriage return character or a control sequence that moves the cursor around. But `[A|a]` cannot match any of these, I think. Is this the *exact* pattern you used?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact pattern.

Comment: No, did not see any change with `tr -d '\r' < chr22.fa`.

Comment: `grep -V` gets `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. I typed in `grep -on "A" chr22.fa` Same result with the bad format.

Comment: Created another shorter test file and problem remains. I don't have experience with hexdump -C. Should I apply the command on the shorter file? If so, the result were put into the question.

Comment: i can confirm now that this behavior is different from GNU grep or busybox or toybox. if using BSD grep i get the same issue

Comment: Thanks—really appreciate the help. How does one download a new grep?

Comment: thats another question ;) what system? easiest probably would be use grep with prefix "busybox" (assuming you have it)

Comment: Sorry. Am I supposed to post it in a different question? As you can tell I'm new here. macOs High Sierra.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46553410

Comment: Please amend question, by amending (editing) the question.

Comment: What is a chromosome txt file?

Comment: In this case, the entire nucleotide sequence of chromosome 22. In bioinformatics we use the FASTA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format#:~:text=In%20bioinformatics%20and%20biochemistry%2C%20the,comments%20to%20precede%20the%20sequences) format to represent protein/nucleic acid (DNA/RNA) sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`
behavior is different from
`grep (GNU grep) 3.40`

BSD grep will give you line number just once instead of repeating the same line number like GNU grep does

you can install GNU grep with

```
brew install grep
```

if you need to use ggrep as default grep you can create a symlink

```
ln -is $(which ggrep) /usr/local/bin/grep
```